# Who starred my chat messages?

Tags: support, chat

While chatting in the Ask Different Chat room, I noticed that a couple of my chat messages were starred. A ★ appeared next to the messages and the message also appeared in the list in the sidebar shown on right.

Specifically this:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50543917#50543917

and, this:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50544374#50544374

Is it possible to see which user(s) starred the message(s)? I was unable to find any way to determine it. Or is it just like upvote/downvote where it isn't possible to determine who voted.

I am just curious to know if this is possible to determine in the UI, and not in actually knowing who did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible; not even ♦ moderators can see this. (We *can* remove stars if a message is no longer important, or somebody is blatantly abusing stars; room owners can also do this.) To see who starred a chat message you will need to have developer-level access to the Stack Exchange chat database.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264580/295232) is an explanation by a former Stack Exchange employee:

> For now, I've added "message starred" to the list of event types for which we don't send the user id to the client.